# Position Multiple Pseudo Elements

Tags: html, css, carousel

I'm creating a carousel with indicators below.
Here's my code:

```
<ul class="product-slick-dots">
    <li aria-hidden="true" data-slick-index="0"></li>
    <li aria-hidden="true" data-slick-index="1"></li>
    <li aria-hidden="true" data-slick-index="2"></li>
    <li aria-hidden="true" data-slick-index="3"></li>
</ul>


.product-slick-dots li {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #00000042;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.product-slick-dots li::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #FFFFFFA6;
    border-radius: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #33333366;
}
```

[image]

I want to make the indicators looks like the left side of the photo, but the result looks like the right side. Why the pseudo elements do not position relatively to their parents `<li>`?

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: relative` to your `li` elements, otherwise the psuedolements are all positioned in the same place (on top of each other) relatively to the first positioned ancestor (or to the `body`)

Answer (score 0):

**set** `.product-slick-dots li {position:relative}`

```css
.product-slick-dots li {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #00000042;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative
}
.product-slick-dots li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #FFFFFFA6;
    border-radius: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #33333366;
}
```

```html
<ul class="product-slick-dots">
    <li aria-hidden="true" data-slick-index="0"></li>
    <li aria-hidden="true" data-slick-index="1"></li>
    <li aria-hidden="true" data-slick-index="2"></li>
    <li aria-hidden="true" data-slick-index="3"></li>
</ul>
```